# while loop fetches same first value

Tags: php

I have used a `while` loop to print database values in row. The query is working as expected, fetching rows according to the total records in the database.

However, the loop is fetching the same value for all rows. If I have `a,b,c,d,e`, then it fetches `a,a,a,a,a` from all the rows.

My code is:

```
<?php 

$sql = mysql_query("
SELECT * 
FROM album 
WHERE status != 'Delete' 
LIMIT {$startpoint} , {$limit}
") or die( mysql_error());

$j = 1; 

while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {

?>
<tr <?php if($j % 2 != '0') echo "style='background-color:#DFFFFE'"; else echo "style='background-color:#EDFFFF'"; ?>>
 <td><input name="check[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo fetch_table_album( $result["aid"], '1', '3' );?>" id="checkbox_<?php echo fetch_table_album( $result["aid"], '1', '3' );?>"></td>
 <td class="navigation"><a href="album.php?aid=<?php echo fetch_table_album( $result["aid"], '1', '4' );?>&id=<?php echo fetch_table_album( $result["aid"], '1', '6' );?>"><?php echo  fetch_table_album( $result["aid"], '1', '5' );?></a></td>
 <td><?php echo fetch_table_album( $result["aid"], '1', '8' );?></td>
 <td><?php echo fetch_table_album( $result["aid"], '1', '10' );?></td>
 <td style="cursor:pointer;"><?php echo fetch_status_image( fetch_table_song( $result["aid"], '1', '13' ));?></td>
</tr>
<?php

    $j++;
}

?>
```

Comment: Did you try running your sql from phpmyadmin..and check removing your fetch_table_album function..?

Comment: Your whitespace for your code formatting does not need to be collapsed down into single lines just because it's within your markup/template. Space it out so you can read it.

Comment: I have checked in phpmyadmin,, Its running well their.

Comment: you need to supply more code - we need to see the function fetch_table_album(), and please format it so it's easily read.

Comment: It doesn't look like the problem's in this code.

Comment: agree with Tim we need to see fetch_table_album() funciton

Comment: What does a `print_r($result)` just after the `while` give?

Answer (score -2):

why you don't use `mysql_fetch_array()` it more simple than using `mysql_fetch_assoc()` like

```
<?php 

$sql = mysql_query("
SELECT * 
FROM album 
WHERE status != 'Delete' 
LIMIT {$startpoint} , {$limit}
") or die( mysql_error());

$j = 1; 

while($result = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {

?>
<tr <?php if($j % 2 != '0') echo "style='background-color:#DFFFFE'"; else echo "style='background-color:#EDFFFF'"; ?>>
 <td><input name="check[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $result["aid"];?>" id="checkbox_<?php echo $result["aid"]);?>"></td>
 <td class="navigation"><a href="album.php?aid=<?php echo $result["aid"];?>&id=<?php echo $result["aid"];?>"><?php echo $result["aid"];?></a></td>
 <td><?php echo $result["aid"];?></td>
 <td><?php echo $result["aid"];?></td>
 <td style="cursor:pointer;"><?php echo $result["aid"];?></td>
</tr>
<?php

    $j++;
}

?>
```